# Android facebook posts from app

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I would like a user to be able to post/"share" to their facebook from my android app. they will be posting a string which contains a link

Although the user may have to log in to facebook to do it, I don't completely believe that I need to "register" the android app with Facebook first to get some oauth key in this case.

The user should be able to click a button, login to their facebook and have it automatically post from there.

Does this need the entire oauth and app registration just for this functionality?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes OAuth work on certain protocols which all application has to agree.
OAuth let your application to access your user profile or can do certain other works on behalf of user, once user has authorize your application.

Though Google allow anonymous OAuth handshaking but still it is not recommended at all.Registering your application means when user will be redirected to login page OAuth system will let user know that from where request is coming and if the application is registered with them or not.

On a curious note whey you don't want to register your application as its only a one time process which will not take more than 10 minutes?